# Host a PXE or network boot image on Windows 7 LAN?

Tags: windows, pxe-boot, netboot

I've never booted with PXE or network share, but now need to reinstall an OS on my laptop with a dead DVD drive and no budget to replace it.

Looking for a free product to host the boot image on Windows 7, then connect to it via PXE or Network Share.  I don't know which is better or easier.  Looking for advice on that too.  This is a one-shot problem and solution.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: so do you have access to a win7 wim file

Comment: I'm hosting the OS image on Win7, its not a Win7 image.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why an [USB-based](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd535816.aspx) install won't work? It will be much simpler and faster. If it all possible, I would try to go that route. PXEboot can be... er... troublesome.

Comment: I'm open to all.  More info?  If it requires a UDF, I can't find mine, grrr.

Answer (score 1):

MDT will do. It's free, and pretty nice.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791